# Error while streaming through Chromecast cast_sender.js

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, chromecast

Add chrome cast according to the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/integrate).

After adding the Chromecast button, I click it, select an available device from the network, and it is connected. The status "Streaming" is visible in the browser, in fact nothing happens, except for the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadMedia' of null
```

**Code:**

```
    cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().setOptions({
        receiverApplicationId: '111111',
        autoJoinPolicy: chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED
    });


    var currentMediaURL =
        'https://.....';
    var contentType = 'mp4';

            var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(currentMediaURL,contentType);
            var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);

            console.log('Below variable -mediaInfo ');
            console.log(mediaInfo);
            console.log('Below variable -request ');
            console.log(request);

            var castSession = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
             console.log('Below variable -castSession ');
            console.log(castSession);

    castSession.loadMedia(request).then(
        function () {
            console.log('Load succeed');
        },
        function (errorCode) {
            console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode);
        });
```

Code testing:

[image: testing]

As I understand it, for some reason, the link to the stream is not sent.
There is an interesting question, why does the link to the stream go to the variable `contentid` although there is a variable`contentUrl`?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @martin i didn't decide

Answer (score 1):

```
var castSession = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
```

There's no session because you must first cast from the browser to the receiving device. After casting, you need to run the function. However, there is an event listener will trigger when there is a session.

```
initializeCastApi = function () {
    cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().setOptions({
        receiverApplicationId: chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID,
    });
    cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().addEventListener(
        cast.framework.CastContextEventType.SESSION_STATE_CHANGED,
        (event) => {
            if (event.sessionState == "SESSION_STARTED") {
                startCasting(cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession());
            }
        },
    );
};
function startCasting(castSession) {
    let mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(url, "video/mp4");
    let request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
    castSession.loadMedia(request).then(
        function () {
            console.log("Load succeed");
        },
        function (errorCode) {
            console.log("Error code: " + errorCode);
        },
    );
}
```